# Disable CTRL-TAB in Flash Builder App

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, keystrokes

When a flash app is loaded in the browser, it default captures the CTRL-TAB keystroke which is needed for changes tabs in modern browsers.

Any ideas on how to configure Flash Builder 4 to not listen for these keystrokes or to bubble them up to the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINAL ANSWER: Not possible. :(

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but when the swf is active inside a web browser it will capture input like that, and shortcuts that normally work in the browser won't do anything - until you click somewhere outside of the swf but still inside the browser. So I don't think you'll be able to write any code to capture a shortcut, then instruct the browser to do something. It's like scrolling, if you have a swf highlighted in a browser and you use the mouse's scroll wheel, it won't scroll the web page.

Hope this helps.

debu

Comment: The user will need to click outside of the swf to use ctrl+tab, same as he'll need to click outside of it to use space to scroll down the webpage. (+1)

Comment: Cheers for the confirmation :)